# Unexpected behaviour: pseudo elements and display: table-cell

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Why does `display: table-cell` behave differently when used on pseudo-elements?

For example, the following elements would be placed side by side:

```
<div style="display:table-cell">one</div>
<div style="display:table-cell">two</div>
```

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tQKzq/**

However, when using `display: table-cell` on a pseudo element, the elements are stacked:

```css
div::after{
   content: "two";
   display: table-cell;   
}
```

```html
<div style="display:table-cell">one</div>
```

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tQKzq/1/**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `::after` pseudo-element is rendered as a child of your `div`, so instead of populating the same row as the `div` cell, it lives in its own anonymous block-level table within the `div` cell, on its own line, beneath the text "one".

If your `div` is displayed as a table row instead, then the text "one" will be contained within its own anonymous table cell, and the `::after` pseudo-element in another cell of its own on the same row:

```css
div {
  display: table-row;
}

div::after {
  content: "two";
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div>one</div>
```

Comment: +1 thanks - the `before` and `after` names are slightly misleading ;)

Comment: Well, it's meant as "before and after the content" not as "before and after the element". This comes clear, when you use it as its originally intended, e.g. to automatically append the text with "..." or prefix it with something else. But you're right, it's a bit misleading.